# Undefined reference in g++ linking

Tags: c++, linker, g++, undefined-reference

Every time I make a new module and try to link it to my main class `(Estudiant.o)` using this line:

`g++ -o red1.exe red1.o %OBJETOS_CPP%\Estudiant.o`

I get this error:

> red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::consultar_DNI() const' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x18):
>   undefined reference to`Estudiant::Estudiant(int)'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::consultar_nota() const' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x74):
>   undefined reference to`Estudiant::afegir_nota(double)'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::~Estudiant()' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined
>   reference to`Estudiant::consultar_nota() const'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::modificar_nota(double)' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x10b):
>   undefined reference to`Estudiant::Estudiant()'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::llegir_estudiant()' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x144):
>   undefined reference to`Estudiant::te_nota() const'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::escriure_estudiant() const' red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x18c):
>   undefined reference to`Estudiant::~Estudiant()'
>   red1.o:red1.cpp:(.text+0x19f): undefined reference to
>   `Estudiant::~Estudiant()'
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   red1.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section`.ctors' collect2.exe: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

And I don't have the original Estudiant.cpp so I thought it might be because different compilers were used for compiling and for the link, but I reinstalled MinGW and I'm still getting this error. 
I also tried to replace all the files and it didn't work.

Comment: what is the result of nm %OBJETOS_CPP%\Estudiant.o?

Comment: And the `Estudiant.o` is recent, so it contains those functions referenced in the error messages?

Comment: @billz It's Windows. Different syntax for shell vars.

Comment: it doesn't matter i tried to put the Estudiant.o file in the same directory and again the same erro.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the source code of the Estudiant.o and compiled another version of it using the code and it worked. I don't know why the same code was compiled on two different machines and one worked and the other one didn't.